# Cause browser to revalidate (but not necessarily refetch) an image

Tags: javascript, html

In my web app we serve up all images with HTTP cache headers good for 24 hours, and also ETags. But sometimes the Javascript client app has cause to suspect that an image might have been updated. In those cases I would like to force the browser to revalidate the image cache, without actually breaking the cache.

For example, I get a user record (in JSON) which has a recent LastUpdated date on it. There are several possible reasons the LastUpdated date could have changed: the user might've changed their nickname, or joined a new board, or changed their image. So there's a good chance the image did not change, but we need to check.

I'm aware that I could re-request the image with a cache breaker appended to the URL. But that would force the image to reload whether it had changed or not, cause two entries in the browser's cache, and force me to update all my images with the new url. What I really want is to make the browser re-request the same URL, and send proper If-None-Match and/or If-Modified-Since headers in the request so that it will get a 304 if the image hasn't changed.

Is there any way to accomplish that in Javascript?

Comment: Sounds like you are over thinking things. Would it really be so terrible to re-fetch the image even if it _might_ not have changed?

Comment: I might potentially have dozens of images to check. Could be a lot to download, especially on a mobile device. If I can revalidate them without reloading every time, I can afford to check them more frequently. Plus I just think it's an interesting question. :)

Comment: A mobile device? Why didn't you mention that in your question? It seems rather pertinent.

Comment: It's not mobile specific. It's just a webapp, but you can't afford to ignore tablets these days.

Comment: Why not just remove the img from the dom and recreate-it ?

Comment: @fmgp - wouldn't the browser just reload from cache without revalidating against the server?

Comment: You're probably right, browsers cache are not always W3C spec compliant

Comment: I thought that was the spec compliant behavior? I put together a quick JSFiddle to see what would happen if I removed and re-added the image. It doesn't refresh from cache in any of the modern browsers I tried. http://jsfiddle.net/Esghw/

Answer (score 0):

Since the image lives at the server, in a cache, the server is where the query needs to take place.
I would do a check before page load, force the server to renew the particular image in cache if needed. The "HTML" part should always assume all img-tags etc are correct.

Best ways of renewing single files in server cache is a different beast IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really work in my circumstance. It's a single-page Javascript app, so the page very rarely reloads. I need to pick up changes that happen between page loads.

Comment: Even if it's a request sent from js, it's still about etags and response codes server-side in my opinion. Caches are both friend and foe when dealing with images.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually rather simple to accomplish.  Make an AJAX request for the image with the `Cache-Control` header set to `max-age=0`.

The server must respond with either the updated image (and a new set of cache headers), or with a 304 **containing a `Cache-Control` header** like `public, max-age=123`.

The 304 with a `Cache-Control` header is very important because it instructs the browser to update the freshness information associated with the resource.

When the request completes, remove the old `<img>` element from the DOM and reinsert a new one pointing to the same `src`.

This works because the *request* `Cache-Control` header tells the browser to ignore its cache and go to the network.  When the browser gets a response back, it updates its cache – even though you don't actually do anything with the AJAX results.

Now when you remove the old element and insert a new one, the browser grabs the recently updated image directly from its cache.

In Chrome's network inspector, you see two requests: the AJAX request, then the request generated by reinserting the `<img>` element.  However, if the server has set the `Cache-Control` headers properly, the second "request" is fulfilled by the browser's cache, and nothing is actually sent over the wire.

```
function updateImage(el) {
    el = $(el);
    var src = el.attr('src');

    $.ajax({
        url: src,
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
        },
        success: function() {
            var parent = el.parent(); 
            el.remove();
            // this assumes that the <img> has no siblings and no attributes/classes/etc...
            parent.append('<img>').attr('src',src);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not work in firefox or IE - only in Chrome